# how to hide a div in the mobile device when scroll the page

Tags: jquery, html

I want to hide a top header when i scroll the page in the mobile device which has social icon.
page url: http://gomodemo.se/port73/
 I have tried following code:

code 1.

```
<script>
jQuery(window).scroll(function ($) {
  var Bottom = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height();
if(Bottom )
{
$('#header_meta').hide();
}
});
</script>
```

code 2.

```
<script>
jQuery("window").scrollDown(function($){
    $("#header_meta").hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Better to use CSS media queries, this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile

Comment: agreed but i have to hide the div on scroll .  When i load the site in the mobile device, I want the div to appear but on scroll want the div to hide.

Comment: Why don't you use a media query which change the `position: fixed` ??

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
.responsive #header .social_bookmarks {
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

[enter link description here](http://gomodemo.se/port73/om-oss/)

enter the `display:none` in media queries